# Creating a new file descriptor from stdout with fcntl fails in files

Tags: c, raku, openbsd, nativecall

I have a simple test file that looks like this:

```pl
use v6.c;
use NativeCall;

sub fcntl(int32, int32 --> int32) is native { * }
sub close(int32 --> int32) is native { * }

my $fd := fcntl($*OUT.native-descriptor, 0);
say $fd;
close($fd);
```

The file descriptor gets returned is -1, which is not what I want. But when I run the same code in a REPL, I get what I'm looking for:

```pl
> use NativeCall
Nil
> sub fcntl(int32, int32 --> int32) is native { * }
sub fcntl (int32 $, int32 $ --> int32) { #`(Sub+{Callable[int32]}+{NativeCall::Native[Sub+{Callable[int32]},Str]}|17126514527616) ... }
> sub close(int32 --> int32) is native { * }
sub close (int32 $ --> int32) { #`(Sub+{Callable[int32]}+{NativeCall::Native[Sub+{Callable[int32]},Str]}|17126514527904) ... }
> my $fd := fcntl($*OUT.native-descriptor, 0)
15
> say $fd
15
> close($fd)
0
```

Why doesn't `fcntl` create a new file descriptor in the file like it does in the REPL?

Edit: I'm running OpenBSD 6.2, Rakudo 2018.02

Comment: Works here. I am using Ubuntu 17.10. Rakudo version 2018.02.1

Comment: What happens if you put it all in one line in the REPL?

Comment: That script outputs `13` on two distinct local CentOS 7 clusters running rakudo-star-2018.01.

Comment: This ended up being a difference in how OpenBSD handles fcntl compared to Linux. I'll explain in the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the [F_DUPFD flag](https://man.openbsd.org/fcntl.2#F_DUPFD) with fcntl (which was 0), OpenBSD requires that the status flags the original file descriptor had be passed on to the new one as well. So this will work:

```pl
use v6.c;
use NativeCall;

constant F_DUPFD = 0;
constant F_GETFD = 1;

sub fcntl(int32, int32, int32 --> int32) is native { * }
sub close(int32 --> int32) is native { * }

sub MAIN() {
    my $out-fd := $*OUT.native-descriptor;
    my $flags  := fcntl($out-fd, F_GETFD, 0);
    my $fd     := fcntl($out-fd, F_DUPFD, $flags);
    say $fd; # 15
    close($fd);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Would you please post a little info on how you found the answer?